# How can I transform a true color image to a jpeg image that I can use in a variable in php

Tags: php, image, copy, jpeg

I am trying to create the jpeg image using the imagejpeg but that outputs the image to browser and I don't want that.

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($im, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
$im=imagejpeg($im, 'test.jpg', 100);
```

It comes up as if it doesn't have a jpg stored inside $im
I am trying to re-size an image and then work with it afterwards in the jpg format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, an image hasn't any type once it was created (from [imageCreateFromJpeg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php), [imageCreateTrueColor()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php), …) : this is simply a ressource.

The conversion in a specific type takes place afterward, when you use [imageJpeg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) for instance. [imageJpeg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) outputs the image to browser or saves it in a file. That's all, it returns nothing more than a boolean which say if the conversion was a success or not.

Comment: Thanks alot. Really helped me out on this one :)